# System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.WindowsStoreUtility

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, namespaces, system.io.file

Looks like I am missing a dll, I tried to get the reference

> Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.WindowsStoreUtility" either
>   14.0.0.0 or an earlier version is not working.

```
Result Message: 

    Test method  “Test001” threw exception: 
    System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.WindowsStoreUtility, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.=== Pre-bind state information ===
    LOG: DisplayName = Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.WindowsStoreUtility, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
     (Fully-specified)
    LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Users/user-name/documents/visual studio 2015/Projects/ bin/Debug
    LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
    Calling assembly : Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a.
    ===
    LOG: This bind starts in LoadFrom load context.
    WRN: Native image will not be probed in LoadFrom context. Native image will only be probed in default load context, like with Assembly.Load().
    LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Users\adan\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects \bin\Debug\App.Config
    LOG: Using host configuration file: 
    LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
    LOG: Post-policy reference: Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.WindowsStoreUtility, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
    LOG: The same bind was seen before, and was failed with hr = 0x80070002.
```